# Горизонтальны скролл

Tags: jquery

Доброе время суток!
Есть сайт пока в тесте:
http://test.luxury-white.com/

Использую плагин:
https://github.com/trgraglia/jquery.horizonScroll.js

Но если подключиться к нему через мобильный телефон то очень плохо работает.

Подскажите пожалуйста как разобраться что бы, можно было нормально работать?

Я не очень хорош в jquery, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: что значит _плохо работает_? чтобы разобраться - разберись с jQuery, потом с плагином

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы под "очень плохо работает" имеете ввиду обработку touch-события(например пролистывание), тогда вам нужно подключить дополнительный плагин для этих целей.

[7 популярных jQuery touch плагинов](http://peak-systems.ru/blog/7-populyarnyih-jquery-touch-plaginov.html)